# Hiding user password field from being displayed using CreatedAtRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm building an ASP.NET Web API and I'm currently implementing very basic user accounts. I have a `User` model which consists of just `Email` and `Password` fields, and I have a `UserController` class with the following action:

```
// POST: api/Users
[ResponseType(typeof(User))]
public IHttpActionResult PostUser(User user)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.Users.Add(user);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = user.Id }, user);
}
```

Everything works perfectly, except when I `POST /api/Users` I get the password field sent back in the response body:

```
{
    "Id":2,
    "Email":"dummy@test.com",
    "Password":"$2a$12$jTACgOlm2eO/OYcV5wrDnO2dmsnbWVnsCRzX1WfQKGsY4sYvh16gm"
}
```

How do I go about making sure that sensitive fields such as user passwords never get output in a response? I'd prefer a method that does it on the model level so that I never accidentally forget to implement it in a controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to always use a [Data Transfer Object (DTO)](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5) when communicating between a client and the server. The example given by [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5) from the Web Api team is very similar to your problem.

I would create a `UserDTO` which wouldn't contain any sensitive data that I wouldn't want to transfer between my clients and the server.
That is how most APIs work, take Facebook, for example, the User passed via [this API call](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user) is not the User from their Domain, it is a representation of a User with just the needed information.

Using a DTO you could control exactly what gets transferred, lowering data size and preventing secure information from leaking.

**UPDATE:** If you go that road you'll probably want to use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/), it reduces the amount of Object to Object mapping you have to do **considerably**.

Answer (score 1):

It's too much to just remove some values we need to create a separate model, better to clean the data before returning, say

```
db.SaveChanges();

user.Password = String.Empty;
user.anyproperty = null;
return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = user.Id }, user);
```

Answer (score 1):

John,

The CreatedAtRoute method is intended to return the URI of a newly created resource.  For example, if you are creating a new product, you may see the return as api/products/1234.  The method will also return the serialized object you provide as a third parameter.  The method is not aware of the nature of the object you are returning therefore it does not recognize any of the fields as sensitive.

In your case, you may clear the password field from the user object or return a completely different object that does not include this field.  You are not forced to return the same object you just created.

Best Regards,
Daniel